# Why are the number of isomorphisms equal to the factorial of the number of elements in the set?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

If we have a set:

```
A = {a,b,c}
```

that is isomorphic to another set:

```
B = {d,e,f}
```

...so that:

```
A ≅ B (isomorphic sets)
```

then the number of isomorphisms in A is:

```
3! = 6
```

But this means that a single isomorphism comes from the following set of permutations:

```
a,b,c
a,c,b
b,a,c
b,c,a
c,a,b
c,b,a
```

Say we pick the last one:

```
c -> b -> a (a single isomorphism)
```

Why does a single isomorphism contain 3 elements? Wouldn't a single isomorphism just be something like `a -> d`, since an isomorphism is an invertible function (from a to d then back to a)?

For example:

if X = {a,b,c,d} we have 24 isomorphisms (4!)

```
X ≅ X
```

ONE such isomorphism is:

```
a ↣ a, b ↣ d, c ↣ b, d ↣ b
```

The reason is that there is 4 ways to choose where `a` goes, and then only 3 ways where `b` goes, etc.

But why is a SINGLE isomorphism all of this:

```
a ↣ a, b ↣ d, c ↣ b, d ↣ b
```

Wouldn't a single isomorphism be this:

```
b ↣ d
```

Comment: This is hard to follow.  There are $3!=6$ bijections from a set with three elements to itself.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: I am wondering why one isomorphism would contain 3 elements (as dictated by the use of a factorial in this example). Why would an isomorphism be something like c to b to a? Shouldn't an isomorphism always contain only 2 elements?

Comment: an isomorphism is a map, so what do you mean by "contain"?

Comment: Isomorphisms don't "contain" things.  That doesn't make sense.  If my three element set is $\{x,y,z\}$ then there are $3$ values $f(x)$ might take.  Having chosen that value, there are then $2$ values $f(y)$ might take. Once you pick that, $f(z)$ is determined.  So there are $3\times 2=6$ isomorphisms.

Comment: @SineoftheTime by "contain" I mean if you were to draw a single isomorphism why would that drawing have 3 elements in it?

Comment: maybe you're referring to the domain?

Comment: @SineoftheTime For example, if we define the relation between the nucleotides of DNA {ACTG} and the nucleotides of RNA {AGCU} we know there are 24 isomorphisms. But why? Why would this number be 4!?

Comment: so I guess you're asking about the number of permutations

Comment: @SineoftheTime yes because permutations are how you count the number of isomorphisms. Thus a single permutation, by definition, must be a single isomorphism. But that single permutation is not a mapping between 2 elements (which is in the definition of isomorphism), rather it's a mapping(?) between 3 elements.

Comment: there's a lot of confusion here, a mapping between to elements is not  an isomorphism

Comment: @lulu I am talking about the relationship between 2 sets that are isomorphic. Shouldn't the isomorphisms be defined in terms of how the elements in one set relate to elements in the other set? And wouldn't this mean that a single isomorphism, if drawn out on paper, would have 2 elements in the drawing? But using factorials means the drawing will have 3 elements.

Comment: If your set has $n$ elements then your bijection (a better term, I think, than "isomorphism" in this case) must specify $n$ values.  Is that what you are asking?  If your set has $3$ elements, say $\{x,y,z\}$ then a typical bijection would be $F(x)=z, F(y)=y, F(z)=x$.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "isomorphism".  You appear to have something non-standard in mind.  That's why I am switching to "bijection" which I hope clears up some ambiguity.

Comment: maybe is better if you include your definition of isomorphism

Comment: @lulu If my set has 3 elements, {,,}, then you are saying that a SINGLE bijection is ()=, ()=, ()=. So does this constitute a SINGLE isomorphism? Does this mean that the permutations are counting the number of possible bijections?

Comment: Of course!  That's standard terminology.

Comment: @lulu Ok I was thinking of an isomorphism as a "connection" between 2 sets, and assuming that a single element (in one set) connected to another single element (in another set) was ONE isomorphism. And that ALL the isomorphisms would be all the possible connections between the individual elements within a set. But actually a SINGLE isomorphism is a single way in which every element in one set "maps" to every element in another set (or itself as the other set). Which is very different. It's like you must take the whole structure as ONE isomorphism. Now it seems obvious. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to have helped!

Comment: Although I still don’t see how the number is the factorial. I challenge anyone to draw the lines and show explicitly that there are 6 isomorphisms between 2 sets, each containing 3 elements.